# Are there any open-source alternatives to ReplayDIRECTOR / Chronon Debugger?

Tags: debugging, logging, virtualization, reverse-debugging

You may be familiar with

- ReplayDirector, http://www.replaysolutions.com/products/replaydirector-for-java-ee
- Chronon, http://www.chrononsystems.com/products/chronon-time-travelling-debugger

they both advertise themselves as 'Java DVRs' - are there any open-source implementations that offer similar (even a subset of their) features?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only ones I know of are

- [WhyLine](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~NatProg/whyline-java.html) 
  Not open source yet, but may eventually be, free download though
- [Omniscient Debugger](http://www.lambdacs.com/debugger/)
- [Jive](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/jive/)
- [Diver](http://diver.sourceforge.net/)
- [TOD](http://pleiad.cl/tod/index.html)

Comment: Unfortunately I [cannot get Omniscient Debugger to work at all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686946/how-to-use-omniscient-debugger) on Java 6, Jive is at least an order of magnitude slower than Chronon, Whyline is unmaintained and "very buggy", and Diver I didn't try but looks like a toy. Therefore I don't think any of these options are production-quality replacements for Chronon. They may be useful for education and research purposes, though.

Answer (score 6):

Omniscient debuggers record the trace data to query afterwards. They are often also called reverse-, back-in-time, bidirectional- or time-travel-debuggers, but I prefer to reserve those terms for debuggers that allow actual reversing in a live program.

[TOD](http://www.pleiad.cl/tod/) is an [open-source](http://www.pleiad.cl/tod/documentation/source.html) omniscient debugger for Java.

[JIVE](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/jive/) is another free omniscient debugger for Java, though not open-source.

The GNU debugger, gdb. It has two modes, one is [process record and replay](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ProcessRecord), the other is true [reverse debugging](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ReverseDebug). It is extremely slow, as it undoes single machine instruction at a time.

And for Python, the extended python debugger prototype, epdb, is also a true reverse debugger. Here is the [thesis](http://mips.complang.tuwien.ac.at/Diplomarbeiten/sabin11.pdf) and here is the [program and the code](http://code.google.com/p/epdb/). I used epdb as a starting point to create a live reverse debugger as part of my MSc degree. The thesis covers the details of the implementation, ***as well as most of the historical approaches to reverse debugging***. It is available online: [Combining reverse debugging and live programming towards visual thinking in computer programming](http://hdl.handle.net/10019.1/96853).

Comment: I think the question is asking for alternatives for the JVM. Alternatives for native applications or other runtimes would be a different question entirely.

Comment: @RobinGreen I disagree with your approach. Though his question does give two examples of 'Java DVRs', it is tagged not with Java, but with 'reverse debugging' in general. He asks for "_any_ open-source implementations that offer similar features". However, in case he meant Java only, the first two items in my answer, TOD and JIVE, adequately answer the question wrt Java. I then added two more for other languages, in case he did mean more. A comprehensive answer that covers what the user might have meant, in order of likelihood, is a good approach which should not get a down-vote, in my opinion

Comment: @Abraham Thank you so much, I have been looking for a reversible debugger for Python for a very long time, and both epdb and the thesis will be of great values to me!